# PHPExcel кодировка. Ошибка файла

Tags: php, phpexcel

Есть код

```
<?php
require_once ('Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php');
require_once ('main.php');
require_once ('PUT.php');



error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_WARNING);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Moscow');
$today = date("d.m.Y");
$Excel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('temmp1.xlsx');
$Excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$aSheet = $Excel->getActiveSheet();


if (isset($_POST['savexcel'])){
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="simple.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
// If you're serving to IE 9, then the following may be needed
header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');

// If you're serving to IE over SSL, then the following may be needed
header ('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
header ('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT'); // always modified
header ('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
header ('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($Excel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
exit;
} else {
```

некоторые вычисления и

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($Excel,'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('simple.xlsx');
```

Каждый раз когда скачивается файл выходит ошибка - `Не удается открыть файл "simple (96).xlsx", так как формат или расширение этого файла являются недопустимыми. Убедитесь, что файл не поврежден и расширение его имени соответствует его формату.`

В чем может быть ошибка? Перепробовал 10 000 вариантов.

Comment: xlsx представляет собой zip архив. Переименуйте файл в zip и откройте. Если не откроется - смотрите файл фаром или каким-то хорошим hex-view, ищите сигнатуру `PK`. Возможно warning попал в output.

Comment: Находится на сервере. Я как-то делал. Всё работало. Но забыл.

Пытаюсь сейчас как-то восстановить, но не выходит.

Файл точно формируется правильно, но толи кодировку менял, толи хз.

Comment: Это на сервере 100%

Comment: Через сайт выводится

Comment: Скачайте файл, распакуйте архив. Создайте аналогичный xlsx документ в офисе - распакуйте архив. Сравните что вышло - найдите 7 отличий. Тогда будет понятно в чём дело. `header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");` -  удалить/закоментить - лишняя строчка. Вопрос - архив распаковуется или нет? Если нет - проверяйте что б не битый был, битый - правим php. Если да - проверьте на валидность xml (что б ие открывал её), если валидны - прийдется тогда шерстить структуру - но думаю до этого не дойдёт.

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_WARNING); ini_set('display_errors', '1');` я не помню как отключить ошибки, любой варнинг или ошибка в output сломает ваш архив. Исправить это, и это `header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");` в первую очередь.

Comment: попробуйте юзать новую библиотку - Spreadsheet. Эта уже давно устарела

Answer (score 0):

Сам столкнулся с тем, что не читались xlsx файлы. Оказалось ( после влезания в глубь самой билиотеки) не отрабатывалась создание класса, который отвечает за работу с архивом (ZipArchive). Этого расширения  просто не было на серверной стороне.

После установки  - всё заработало.